# Change Wayland to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, login-screen, wayland

I have been testing Ubuntu 17.10. I like it, but when I turn on my PC (with Ubuntu 17.10), the login screen uses Wayland, and my GPU doesn’t support it. After login, it automatically change to Xorg and it works normally.

How can I change from using Wayland to Xorg on the login screen permanently?

Comment: Perhaps change from gdm to lightdm

Answer (score 1):

Click the little gear-symbol to the left of the login button, and choose "Gnome on Xorg', then the login will default to the Xorg session.